# How to check if your node.js application's version is the latest?

Tags: node.js

As [my node.js application](https://github.com/bevry/docpad) is a command line application that is run by the user directly. It would make sense for it to phone the github repo and compare its local version against the lastest on the master branch on the github repo. And if the version is outdated, display a message to the user.

So how would one accomplish this phone home and compare versions?

Comment: Are you just posting questions and answering them all yourself?

Comment: Yes, the practice of asking and answering questions that you already have an answer to, that will add value to the community, and that haven't already been asked - [is encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Do you have an objection?

Comment: No objection, nope. I just saw the string of questions coming in and immediately being answered by you and thought it was odd ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a solution to do this myself. Requires the dependency [bal-util](https://github.com/balupton/bal-util) (so `npm install bal-util`). Here's the code:

Source code of the `packageCompare` function can be found here: https://github.com/balupton/bal-util/blob/master/src/lib/compare.coffee

### CoffeeScript

```
# Prepare
balUtil = require('bal-util')
pathUtil = require('path')
debug = false

# Compare
balUtil.packageCompare({
    local: pathUtil.join(__dirname, '..', 'package.json')
    remote: 'https://raw.github.com/bevry/docpad/master/package.json'
    newVersionCallback: (details) ->
        if debug
            console.log """
                There is a new version of #{details.local.name} available, you should probably upgrade...
                current version:  #{details.local.version}
                new version:      #{details.remote.version}
                grab it here:     #{details.remote.homepage}
                """
        else
            console.log "There is a new version of #{details.local.name} available"
})
```

### JavaScript

```
// Prepare
var balUtil, debug, pathUtil;
balUtil = require('bal-util');
pathUtil = require('path');
debug = false;

// Compare
balUtil.packageCompare({
  local: pathUtil.join(__dirname, '..', 'package.json'),
  remote: 'https://raw.github.com/bevry/docpad/master/package.json',
  newVersionCallback: function(details) {
    if (debug) {
      return console.log("There is a new version of " + details.local.name + " available, you should probably upgrade...\ncurrent version:  " + details.local.version + "\nnew version:      " + details.remote.version + "\ngrab it here:     " + details.remote.homepage);
    } else {
      return console.log("There is a new version of " + details.local.name + " available");
    }
  }
});
```